# Is it 'illegal' to include a GENDER type in vCard 3.0?

Tags: vcf-vcard

I understand that vCard 4.0 will introduce some commonly used contact property fields (types) like GENDER, ANNIVERSARY, etc. There is no standard way to represent these in vCard 3.0 format.

My question is what should a client do if a vCard 3.0 object contains a GENDER type. Will that make it an invalid vCArd, or just that clients will ignore those fields?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some clients will add a `X-GENDER` property.  However, since it's an extended property, there's no guarantee that the application reading the vCard will detect it.

```
X-GENDER:Male
```

Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VCard#vCard_extensions

You could also just go ahead and include a `GENDER` property, even though it's not part of the 3.0 specs.  The specs say that if the vCard contains a property that the consumer does not recognize, the consumer must ignore that property and continue parsing the rest of the vCard.

Comment: Michael, thanks. But that is not my question. What does it mean to have a GENDER: property in a vCard 3.0 - from a compliance perspective? Will the file be rejected? What does the standard say, for e.g.? That sort of thing.

Comment: @Karra The specs say that consumers must ignore properties they don't recognize and continue parsing the rest of the vCard.  So no, including GENDER in a 3.0 vCard will not break it.